How to return smart pointers and covariance in C++
I am following this tutorial to understand how to return smart pointers and covariance in C++.
  #include <memory>
  #include <iostream>

  class cloneable
  {
  public:
     virtual ~cloneable() {}

     std::unique_ptr<cloneable> clone() const
     {
        return std::unique_ptr<cloneable>(this->clone_impl());
     }

  private:
     virtual cloneable * clone_impl() const = 0;
  };
   
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  template <typename Derived, typename Base>
  class clone_inherit: public Base
  {
  public:
     std::unique_ptr<Derived> clone() const
     {
        return std::unique_ptr<Derived>(static_cast<Derived *>(this->clone_impl()));
     }

  private:
     virtual clone_inherit * clone_impl() const override
     {
        return new Derived(*this); // getting error here 
     }
  };


  class concrete : public clone_inherit<concrete, cloneable>
  {
    
  };

  int main()
  {
    std::unique_ptr<concrete> c = std::make_unique<concrete>();
  }

When I execute this example I get the following error:
  /tmp/0RmVdQYjfA.cpp: In instantiation of 'clone_inherit<Derived, Base>* clone_inherit<Derived, Base>::clone_impl() const [with Derived = concrete; Base = cloneable]':
  /tmp/0RmVdQYjfA.cpp:30:28:   required from here
  /tmp/0RmVdQYjfA.cpp:32:14: error: no matching function for call to 'concrete::concrete(const clone_inherit<concrete, cloneable>&)'
     32 |       return new Derived(*this);
        |              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  /tmp/0RmVdQYjfA.cpp:37:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr concrete::concrete()'
     37 | class concrete : public clone_inherit<concrete, cloneable>
        |       ^~~~~~~~
  /tmp/0RmVdQYjfA.cpp:37:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
  /tmp/0RmVdQYjfA.cpp:37:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr concrete::concrete(const concrete&)'
  /tmp/0RmVdQYjfA.cpp:37:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const clone_inherit<concrete, cloneable>' to 'const concrete&'
  /tmp/0RmVdQYjfA.cpp:37:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr concrete::concrete(concrete&&)'
  /tmp/0RmVdQYjfA.cpp:37:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const clone_inherit<concrete, cloneable>' to 'concrete&&'

To fix this error in line 32, I had to return exactly the return pointer to a Derived class as follows:
  //   return  new static_cast<Derived*>(*this); to replace with 
  return new Derived(static_cast<const Derived&>(*this));

Can someone suggest the proper way to fix this?

@wohlstad thank youu I fixed it

Are you stuck on C++17? this is way easier with C++23 explicit object arguments

@Caleth can you put it as a answer :) thanks

You can add a private implicit or explicit cast operator:
template <typename Derived, typename Base>
class clone_inherit : public Base {
 public:
  std::unique_ptr<Derived> clone() const {
    return std::unique_ptr<Derived>(static_cast<Derived *>(this->clone_impl()));
  }

 private:
  // added here
  explicit operator const Derived &() const {
    return static_cast<const Derived &>(*this);
  }

  virtual clone_inherit *clone_impl() const override {
    return new Derived(*this);  // not getting error here
  }
};



Hi @3CxEZiVlQ, so any other ways to do this or this is the proper way of doing this?

Anyway thank youu

It's arguable like the whole code in the question, but not so bad.

With C++ 23 explicit object arguments, this pattern becomes very simple:
class cloneable
{
public:
    template<typename Self>
    std::unique_ptr<Self> clone(this const Self& self) const {
        return std::make_unique<Self>(self);
    }
};

This avoids having to specify the derived type, as it is deduced.

thank youu, just to know )
